# how to use EXIST instead of IN using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

How can i "convert" this query for not use IN, i read about in is slow compare it to exists

```
SELECT * FROM kx_examenes_diagnostico.examenes t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM kx_examenes_diagnostico.examenes_aplicados t2 WHERE t2.alumno_id=812 AND t2.examen_id=t1.examen_id
) AND t1.examen_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,,50,159,635,456,780,12,63,45);
```

Im using MySQL, i dont know how can i use exist with my values that im compared (inside of in clause) do i have to use OR's? Is possible?

Thanks

Comment: `in` is fine when you have a list of constants.  The performance issue is when there is a subquery.

Comment: When the `IN` clause selects on a primary key/indexed column it's nearly as fast as possible, because the row can be directly obtained from the index, which should be sortable by binary search.

Comment: "In" and "exists" don't necessarily do the same thing.  There is a time and a place for both.  Getting the proper results should be paramount.  Then you can worry about speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you would want to rewrite the query to eliminate the IN list. The query could be rewritten to replace the `col IN (literal list)` predicate, but that won't improve performance.

---

If you are looking to improve performance, it's much more likely you'd want to eliminate the

```
 NOT EXISTS (correlated_subquery)
```

predicate, and replace it using an "anti-join" pattern, something like this:

```
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM kx_examenes_diagnostico.examenes t1
  LEFT
  JOIN kx_examenes_diagnostico.examenes_aplicados t2
    ON t2.examen_id=t1.examen_id
   AND t2.alumno_id=812
 WHERE t1.examen_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,50,159,635,456,780,12,63,45)
   AND t2.examen_id IS NULL
```

The "anti-join" pattern is an outer join (to include rows from `t1` that didn't have any matching rows in `t2`) combined with a predicate (WHERE clause) that eliminates rows that did have a match.

For optimum performance of this particular query, you'd likely want indexes

```
... ON examenes (examen_id)

... ON examenes_aplicados (examen_id, alumno_id)
```

Depending on the cardinality of the `alumno_id` column, this index might be better:

```
... ON examenes_aplicados (alumno_id, examen_id)
```

Either of those two indexes on `examenes_aplicados` are "covering indexes", which means that MySQL can satisfy the query by accessing index pages, without a need to visit the pages in the underlying table. We'd expect MySQL `EXPLAIN` to show "`Using index`" for the access of that table.

---

**UPDATE:**

I avoided answering the questions you asked, and answered a fundamentally different question. To answer the questions you asked:

**Q: do i have to use OR's?**

No, you don't have to use the OR keyword. The IN list can be replaced with an equivalent predicate that does not use any `OR` keyword.

**Q: Is possible?**

Yes, it is possible to replace the `IN (list)` predicate with an `EXISTS` clause. But you do *not* want to do that, unless your goal is horrendous performance, and you have a desire for the DBA to hunt you down to chastise you, publicly humiliate you, and beat you about the head.